# Keep getting this error message "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Tags: sklearn-pandas

The code below is triggering a AttributeError: can't set attribute. I'm still new to programming so am having a difficult time figuring out why this error is occurring. Any help is appreciated.

```
import cimcb_lite as cb

cv = cb.cross_val.kfold(model=cb.model.PLS_SIMPLS,X=XTknn,                                 
                        Y=Ytrain,                               
                        param_dict={'n_components': [1,2,3,4,5]},                  
                        folds=5,                                     
                        bootnum=100) 

cv.run()
```

seeing this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/rs/f6nsd1894354_821jj157jnr0000gn/T/ipykernel_30013/1292624611.py in <module>
      8 
      9 # run the cross validation
---> 10 cv.run()
     11 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cimcb_lite/cross_val/kfold.py in run(self)
     82     def run(self):
     83         """Runs all functions prior to plot."""
---> 84         self.calc_ypred()
     85         self.calc_stats()
     86         if self.bootnum > 1:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cimcb_lite/cross_val/kfold.py in calc_ypred(self)
     55             model_i = self.model(**params_i)
     56             # Full
---> 57             model_i.train(self.X, self.Y)
     58             ypred_full_i = model_i.test(self.X)
     59             self.ypred_full.append(ypred_full_i)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cimcb_lite/model/PLS_SIMPLS.py in train(self, X, Y)
     77         # Calculates and store attributes of PLS SIMPLS
     78         Xscores, Yscores, Xloadings, Yloadings, Weights, Beta = self.pls_simpls(X, Y, ncomp=self.n_component)
---> 79         self.model.x_scores_ = Xscores
     80         self.model.y_scores_ = Yscores
     81         self.model.x_loadings_ = Xloadings

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: It seems it's having some problem with 
`self.model.x_scores_ = Xscores` this line. Maybe some mismatch between X and Y?

Comment: it's probably referring to `# Calculates and store attributes of PLS SIMPLS` these attributes.

Comment: and don't worry, reading these stack traces/debug messages becomes easier with time